# Inactive router on quagga

Tags: networking, interface, quagga

Im trying to connect 5 virtual machines using quagga but for some reason one of my virtual routers appears as inactive, when I use "show ip route" my router with IP "192.168.2.2" is inactive https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejj0I.jpg

How can I activate my router?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but try to check your interfaces (their state, e.g. if they are up) using 'show interfaces' command. Also see here: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps708/products_tech_note09186a008015bfd6.shtml#inact

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have no route towards 192.168.2.2, so Quagga is unable to install a route through it.  You are probably missing a kernel or static route towards 192.168.2.0/24.